# Change GRUB default start option (SO)

Tags: linux, grub

Is it possible to change the default start option from the GRUB command line?

I have 2 options Fedora and Other. Currently the Fedora is the default. Is it possible to change it to Other from the GRUB command line, and make it permanent?

thanks.

Comment: sry for that. I asked if its possible to change it from the GRUB COMMAND LINE, not from the terminal. I dont have access to that.

Answer (score 0):

in /boot/grub/menu.lst is option default, you should set it for another value, for exmaple - 0 - feodra, 1, other

Comment: This will be overwritten each time `update-grub` runs - e.g. after every kernel change. The file even says "# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
" - therefore, the settings should go into `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: I asked if its possible to change it from the GRUB COMMAND LINE, not from the terminal. I dont have access to that.